# Is it possible to have a fullscreen modal image that fits inside the browser window (no scrolling, no cropping) with Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I tried various CSS tricks to try to make sure my Bootstrap Modal (width:100%,height:100%) fills the screen. I am able to make the .modal-dialog fill the screen and ignore the areas outside it's viewport. But the image content is too tall and just extends outside of the .modal-dialog. That means if I want to see the bottom of the image, I need to scroll down.

I just want to shrink the image so the entire image is visible and keeps its aspect ratio.

I would like to add that all solutions (including using .img-responsive) does not work because it fits to screen based on the entire scrollable region. I want it to fit inside the viewport (and exclude the scrollable area).

Comment: can you provide snippet - some code of he problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you're keeping the .modal-dialog element smaller than the viewport height. But one technique would be to set the max-height of the image to something just under `100vh`. That will make sure the image is never taller than the viewport.

```css
.max-height-80vh {
  max-height: 80vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal">Launch modal</button>

<div id="modal" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <img class="img-fluid max-height-80vh" src="http://fpoimg.com/2000x2000" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```